# row and column coordinates in a text file

Tags: python, pandas, position

I have a text file with lots of data, and I only want to edit one column. Coordinates start at row 4, column 111 and end at row 55, column 111. Here an exemple :

```
//  typTpt  TypTpt  NomTypTpt    LibTypTpt                                                         TypDem Medic Motif Mutat Classe Dispo AnnDep AnnRdv AnnExclu HorRdv Ste TSupp TypHos AC , Etb_Debiteur , Art80 , WithForfait , RetSelAutre
        01,      E, Entr‚e     ,"Entr‚e                   "                                       ,     E,    N,             , 0     ,             ,
        02,      E, Entr‚eUrg  ,"D‚part                              "                            ,     E,    N,    U,    S,    02,    O,IE    ,IEAH  , E      ,     D,  O,    0,     L, S ,              , 1     ,             ,
        40,      E, Entr‚eMEG  ,"D‚part                             "                             ,     I,    N,    u,    S,    02,    O,I     ,I     ,        ,     D,  N,    0,     L,
```

I want to edit the column Medic by putting B instead of N :

```
//  typTpt  TypTpt  NomTypTpt    LibTypTpt                                                         TypDem Medic Motif Mutat Classe Dispo AnnDep AnnRdv AnnExclu HorRdv Ste TSupp TypHos AC , Etb_Debiteur , Art80 , WithForfait , RetSelAutre
        01,      E, Entr‚e     ,"Entr‚e                   "                                       ,     E,    B,    E,    S,    01,    O,IEA@  ,IEAH  , EA     ,     D,  N,    0,     L,   ,              , 0     ,             ,
        02,      E, Entr‚eUrg  ,"D‚part                              "                            ,     E,    B,    U,    S,    02,    O,IE    ,IEAH  , E      ,     D,  O,    0,     L, S ,              , 1     ,             ,
        40,      E, Entr‚eMEG  ,"D‚part                             "                             ,     I,    B,    u,    S,    02,    O,I     ,I     ,        ,     D,  N,    0,     L,
```

I have already thought about using the pandas module but it does not work with my text because it is not a table and I cannot rearrange it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("d:/art80_typTpt_v2.txt", sep="\s+")
df.loc[df["Medic"] == "B" ,"Medic"] = "A"
print(df)

df.to_csv('d:/test.txt',sep='\t', index=False)
```

Can we do a function with python to position itself at a specific column and row? If so is it possible to modify just one column among lots of data such as the Medic column?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file has some consistency issues. At first glance, it looks like it is a comma-separated CSV file but not every line has the same amount of commas.
Make sure that every line in your CSV file has the same amount of commas and then you can read it with:

```
df = pd.read_csv("d:/art80_typTpt_v2.txt", sep=",")
```

The comma separator *sep=","* is standard, but sometimes tabulators *sep="\t"* or semicolons *sep=";"* are used.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go line by line and replace the required character at the correct position since strings in Python are arrays.

```
new_lines = []
with open('input_file.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        new_line = line
        if (len(line)>109 and line[110]=='N'):
            new_line = line[:109]+'B'+line[111:]
        new_lines.append(new_line)

with open('edited_file.txt', mode='wt') as myfile:
    myfile.write(''.join(new_lines))
```

Comment: your program doesn't work on my text file because the medic column is not column 114, it's the 111th column. So I put if (len (line)> 110 and line [111] == 'N'): new_line = line [: 110] + 'B' + line [112:] but it doesn't seem to work, I don't understand why.

Comment: I think your index is off by 1, the 111th column is line[110], so try `if(len(line)>109 and line[110]=='N'): new_line = line[:109] + 'B' + line[111:]`

Comment: My index was different because I omitted the `encoding='utf-8'` (my bad) so now it should work correctly for you too, I've edited the answer as well